# PL/SQL ORAERR 6550

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package in my oracle databse I need to call from a ANSI-C service which lives in a tuxedo enviroment.

I have debugged the whole thing down to a the last row. What I mean with debugged is that it kept  coredumping, but that fixed. So this is the code I'm trying to run.

**QUESTION**
What is wrong with the folowing statment?
This gives me an **ORAERR** - **6550** which in turn is a **PL/SQL compilation error**?

**VARIABLES**

```
VARCHAR sql_sats[500];
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
short i_slask;

long id_session_sql;
long id_pdb_journal_typ_sql;
long id_pdb_journal_sql_ut;
long id_pers_sql;

char id_objekt_sql[200];
char objektsbeskrivning_sql[200];

EXEC SQL VAR id_objekt_sql IS STRING;
EXEC SQL VAR objektsbeskrivning_sql IS STRING;

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

//SET VALUES!
id_session_sql = 123;
strcpy(id_objekt_sql, "54582");
id_pers_sql = atoi("111111111111");
strcpy(objektsbeskrivning_sql, "ID_ANST");
id_pdb_journal_typ_sql = 999;


strcpy(sql_sats.arr,                        
" BEGIN                                                             "                   
" id_pdb_journal_sql_ut :=  PKG_JOURNAL.F_PO_SKAPA_JOURNAL_INIT (   "
"   :id_session_sql,                                                "
"   :id_objekt_sql,                                                 "
"   :id_pers_sql,                                                   "
"   :objektsbeskrivning_sql,                                        "
"   :id_pdb_journal_typ_sql                                         "
"   );                                                              "
" END;                                                              "
"); //END STRCPY

sql_sats.len = strlen(sql_sats.arr);

EXEC SQL PREPARE sql_sats_sql FROM :sql_sats;

EXEC SQL EXECUTE sql_sats_sql USING :id_session_sql, :id_objekt_sql,
     :id_pers_sql, :objektsbeskrivning_sql, :id_pdb_journal_typ_sql;
```

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you did not declare your varible `id_pdb_journal_sql_ut`:

```
DECLARE
  id_pdb_journal_sql_ut  <TYPE>;
BEGIN
  id_pdb_journal_sql_ut :=  PKG_JOURNAL.F_PO_SKAPA_JOURNAL_INIT (
  [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning  value to `id_pdb_journal_sql_ut`, but that isn't declared in the PL/SQL; so it isn't surprising that you get a PL/SQL compilation error. That's from compiling the anonymous block you're running, not the function you're calling (or its package).

Since you have a `long` with that name I guess you meant it to be a bind variable:

```
strcpy(sql_sats.arr,                        
" BEGIN                                                             "
" :id_pdb_journal_sql_ut :=  PKG_JOURNAL.F_PO_SKAPA_JOURNAL_INIT (  "
"   :id_session_sql,                                                "
"   :id_objekt_sql,                                                 "
"   :id_pers_sql,                                                   "
"   :objektsbeskrivning_sql,                                        "
"   :id_pdb_journal_typ_sql                                         "
"   );                                                              "
" END;                                                              "
); //END STRCPY

...

EXEC SQL EXECUTE sql_sats_sql USING :id_pdb_journal_sql_ut, :id_session_sql,
    :id_objekt_sql, :id_pers_sql, :objektsbeskrivning_sql,
    :id_pdb_journal_typ_sql;
```

You also have an extra double-quote at the end of your `strcpy`, but that would stop it compiling, so hopefully that's been introduced when you created this question.

If the package and its function are declared as they appear to be then this compiles and runs OK.